# In Django custom MultiWidget how can get sub-widgets ids

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-widget, django-multiwidget

In Django how to can get **id**s of sub-widgets that added to custom **`MultiWidget`**, for example if I want to attach a JavaScript code to rendered widgets how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In regular django custom widgets pattern of auto **id** has two parts that separated by underscore **id_widget-name** but in custom `MultiWidget` all sub-widgets id pattern contains three parts **id_widget-name_widget-index**, and we can make widgets auto-id similar below:

```
class MyMultiWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
    ...
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        ids = ['id_%s_%d' % (name, index) for index in range(len(self.widgets))]
        ...
```